# Spring Boot: How do I specify execute order of different schema.sql files?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I have created a table that has a foreign key constraint on [spring-session-jdbc](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-jdbc)'s `spring_session` table. The main motivation is that spring-session would delete the rows so that it would cascade and delete entries associated with the actual session. It became a "only works on my machine" problem because only me have had the table already in place when I start the development server. It would only work if others comment out the table first, initialize the server, then revert and do it again. Otherwise, `nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Failed to open the referenced table 'spring_session'`.

I think the solution is to specify the run order of (or dependencies between) the initialization sql files. I cannot find that setting after some searching, so I am here.

schema.sql:

```sql
drop table if exists foo;
create table if not exists foo (
    sid char(36) not null,
    foreign key (sid) references spring_session (session_id) on delete cascade,
    -- other columns and constraints
);
```

Possible workarounds:

Workaround #1: put an `alter table add constraint` statement like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508039/2185599) in `data.sql`.

Workaround #2: grab spring-session-jdbc's `schema.sql` and put it into my `schema.sql`, then set `spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=never` in `application.properties`.

Answer (score 2):

U can try flyway,it can manage your init sql files by giving them a version number. And it can record which sql have been executed, so if add another sql files, it will excute the sql you added, pass the others that have been executed.

Comment: While that would definitely work, I would have to manage the migration of the spring-session schema.sql too. With the scope of the project this small, I would rather use workaround #2 that I just added to the question.